AM radio over rainforest
Where to find information about the AM radio reception at tropical rainforest environment?
Here in Colombia exists the more humid environment of the planet.
I can't find information about am radio quality at that place.
But in general terms the himidity and dense rainforest is a big obstacle?
Edit 1:  AM radio freq: 535 KHz to 1705 KHz.
Edit 2:
source, full weather comparision with other places. Quibdó , Choco, Colombia vs Sao Paulo Br and others.
https://weatherspark.com/compare/y/21538~23912~30268~15463/Comparison-of-the-Average-Weather-in-Quibd%C3%B3-New-York-City-S%C3%A3o-Paulo-and-San-Jos%C3%A9

Ando, lightning from thunderstorms might be a bigger obstacle to a radio receiver's reception quality. A radio transmitter installation should be designed to absorb a lightning strike, or at least divert it to ground.

"AM radio" without qualification like "shortwave" is usually below 3MHz and that's also where the tropical condition (high QRN) is unique.

@MarcusMüller At least in North America, the AM broadcast band is defined as mf. In Europe, I'm pretty sure it's different. :-)

@MikeWaters up to the edit, broadcast wasn't mentioned anywhere! Just "am radio", and considering OP is probably not a native speaker, asking them to state their frequencies explicitly to avoid misinterpretation seemed sensible :-) (yep, in Germany, when someone says "AM Rundfunk", they'd be likely to refer to LW or SW, as analog MW has been switched of in nearly the whole EU. Only Great Britain has popular channels that still get transmitted on MW – they've slept through the continent going for FM/UHF in the 70s and DAB since 2005. That's been some really intense sleep.)

UK might be asleep. How would you characterize this? https://www.congress.gov/bill/118th-congress/senate-bill/1669#:~:text=Reported%20to%20Senate%20(09%2F12%2F2023),-AM%20Radio%20for&text=This%20bill%20requires%20the%20Department,stations%20installed%20as%20standard%20equipment.

@RyujiAB1WX the US have a different spatial problem than UK :) No matter how hard you try, you can't drive 200km straight in a deserted area in Europe. AM requirements hence make some sense (and made some more sense in the cold war / nuclear war scenario that dominated the post-WW2 era). What I will say is that it's a shame that aside from Australia, all large-area highly-industrialized nations seem to be sleeping on DRM, whereas nations like India demonstrate that they can actually make a difference in the lives of people that could barely receive a single AM channel before, while saving …

… massive amounts of electrical energy on broadcast transmitter operations.

"535 KHz to 1705 KHz" in the Americas is AM. That's just a fact.

In tropical areas, the 520 – 1700 kHz (medium wave) AM broadcast band is too noisy (too much QRN, "static electricity discharge", i.e. lightning), so instead, 2300 – 2500 kHz (still medium frequency) is used for broadcast. Car radios intended for those regions have a separate band covering upward of 1.6 MHz up to 2.9 MHz.
At those frequencies, the rain/moisture or the tree has almost no impact on the propagation. If anything, wet ground generally extends the ground wave reach.
There probably are differences in the ionospheric D and E layers (for example, radio blackout is more intense) but the normal service area of medium wave AM broadcast depends on the direct/ground wave and not skywave, so this should have little impact except for long-distance BCL (broadcast listening) hobbyists.

added a definition of QRN, because I suspect that the asker might not be familiar with that terminology. I couldn't find what BCL means, could you explain?

I do have a technical follow-up question, if you don't mind: if QRN is the problem, wouldn't it be advisable to use other modes (FM)?

VHF FM broadcast delivers superior sound quality and is more immune to noise, but each transmission site has a smaller service area contour due to more rapid ground wave attenuation and possibly due to terrain.

Thanks. The main question will be if may be better investigate about Ip / Streaming solutions --if possible-- in area or look for a AM radio station partner if the main content is voice/education, so the listeners canot be frustrated with the audio quality.

@Ando If the Internet connection is available, I personally prefer podcast-type distribution for educational content so that listeners can copy the material to their local device for stable playback, and are free to repeat important or difficult parts. If real-time news-like content, both AM and streaming simultaneously may be most effective. I would also look into 120m, 90m, and 60m broadcast bands if those receivers are common in the target region.

Colombian national radio seems to use MW AM (10 kHz separation) and FM transmission, no 120m, etc.
